# Why does this fail? Find numbers between 100 and 400 (both included) where each digit of a number is an even number

Tags: python

Why is my program unable to run? I am a beginner.

I could have done it with `range` but I wanted it to keep it simple.

```
a=100
b=400
while a!=b:
    j=0
    d=a
    while d!=0:
        k=d%10
        d=d/10
        if(k%2==0):
            continue
        else:
            j=j+1
            break
    a=a+1
    if j==0:
        print(a-1,",")
    else:
        continue
```

Comment: `[number for number in range(100,401,2) if all(not (int(i)%2) for i in str(number))]`

Comment: Why do you increment a by 1? Not sure what your inner while should accomplish. If you want it simple, use a range, get the single digits and check each digit `[a//100,(a-a//100)//10, a-(a//10*10)]` instead of doing whatever you do - or use the str() of a number as iterable and convert the digit back to ints for checking: `[number for number in range(100,401,2) if all(not (i%2) for i in [number//100,(number-number//100*100)//10, number-(number//10*10)])]`

Comment: A range *is* simpler, it keeps the information about the loop controls in one place, rather than sprinkling it around like you do now.

Comment: Thank you so much .The problem was with division.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem in your program is this line.

```
d=d/10
```

You should use integer division here

```
d = d // 10
```

Improved version of your solution

```
a, b = 100, 400
while a != b:
    d = a
    while d != 0:
        d, k = divmod(d, 10)
        if k % 2 != 0:
            break
    else:
        print(a, end=', ')
    a += 2
```

Comment: The div method calculates both x / y and x % y and returns both the values.But here we are suppose to use // division and not / right?

Comment: For integers, `divmod(a, b)`  is the same as `(a // b, a % b)` from [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#divmod)